# Is this version of Caratheodory's Extension Theorem true?

Tags: measure-theory

While trying to memorize Caratheodory's Extension Theorem, I came up with a slight variant that's a little easier to state, and perhaps a little stronger.

> **Claim.** Let $\mu_0$ be a premeasure on an algebra $\mathcal{A}_0$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}_0$ and $P$ denote the poset of measures $\mathcal{A} \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ extending $\mu_0$. Then:
>
> - $P$ has a greatest element, call it $\mu$, and
> - The elements of $P$ agree on $\mathcal{A}_\mu$, defined as the collection of all $S \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $S$ is a $\sigma$-finite set with respect to $\mu$.

My question is simply whether or not this true, and if so, whether or not it's a straightforward consequence of the usual statement of the theorem.